# PHP - Find first letter character in string

Tags: php, regex

I have one string like below

```
$string = "1234@#$ABCFG3478&*";
```

Now I want first character from this string that is not numeric or special character, It should be only A-a to Z-z.

Means, I need only "A" from this string.

I have try this formula:

```
 substr($string, 1);
```

Comment: The dollar sign in your string will give a notice (undefined variable) you should change your double quotes to single quotes to avoid it.

Comment: @jigsVirani if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex:

```
$string = '1234@#$ABCFG3478&*';

if (preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $string, $match)) {
    $firstLetter = $match[0];
} else {
    // there's no letters in given string
}
```

Comment: I suggest you incorporate @Daan's advice into your answer because otherwise your good solution won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Here I just replace every character  with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) which isn't in the range `a-zA-Z` with an empty string and then I just grab the first letter)

```
$string = '1234@#$ABCFG3478&*';
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string)[0];
```